# Issue displaying number on my GUI using tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to display the answer to linear regression. I can print the answer in the console with just print(regr.fit(X_train,y_train) , but I can't make it work and display in my GUI.

```
def LinearRegression():
    df2.interpolate(method ='linear', inplace = True)
    
    X = np.array(df2['doors']).reshape(-1, 1)
    y = np.array(df2['persons']).reshape(-1, 1)
    
    # Separating the data into independent and dependent variables
    # Converting each dataframe into a numpy array
    # since each dataframe contains only one column
    df2.dropna(inplace = True)
    
    # Dropping any rows with Nan values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
    
    regr = LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    LR = regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
  
    answer1.configure(text=LR)


button4 = Button( window , text = "Run algorithm!" , command = LinearRegression ).grid(pady=30)    
    
answer1 = Label(window, text="",font=('papyrus',14), bg="wheat") 
answer1.grid(column=1, row=0)  

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: line 7, in LinearRegression
    df2.interpolate(method ='linear', inplace = True)
    ^^^
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Comment: `RecursionError` should be raised because `LinearRegression()` is called inside `LinearRegression()`.